# In Java, can a subclass replace an attribute with that attribute's subclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Doing something like this:

```
class Foo {
    Foo foo;
    ...
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    ...
}

class Baz extends Foo {
    Bar foo;
    ...
}
```

works, but I'm not sure if in class `Baz`, `Bar foo` actually replaces the instance of `Foo foo` from the parent class `Foo`. In fact, in the Eclipse debugger, it seems as though on a `Baz` instance, we have both a `Foo foo` *and* a `Bar foo`.

I'll test this in a bit if I don't get an answer. I was expecting to be able to "override" the `Foo foo` with the `Bar foo`.

Comment: *I'll test this in a bit if I don't get an answer.* Please test before asking.

Comment: With all due respect, getting keywords (*hiding*) from the community here really helped me finding the relevant docs. Experimenting is more tedious (esp. in Java), and doesn't always yield a comprehensive answer; for example I did not expect the behaviour that when a `Baz` instance calls an inherited method from `Foo`, that the `Foo foo` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not *replacing* that `foo` field in the `Foo` class, you're just declaring a new one that will *shadow* that declaration (that is, just using `foo` inside `Baz` will refer to the `Bar` field).

You can always just assign a `Bar` instance to the `Foo foo` variable.